# Imacros Login with Captcha

Tags: javascript, imacros

Please ! i am newbie here too with Imacros.
i tried to create my first own Imacros Login ,but i did fill the user name and password ,but my problem is the captcha how to do it , my imacros code lines is

```html
VERSION BUILD=8881205 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=http://www.paidverts.com/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:LOGIN
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:loginFrm ATTR=ID:email CONTENT=xxxxxxxxx
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=ID:loginFrm ATTR=ID:password CONTENT=zzzzzzzzzzz
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ID:loginFrm ATTR=ID:remember CONTENT=YES
FRAME NAME="I0_1423080140232"
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ROLE:presentation&&CLASS:recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark&&TXT:
FRAME NAME="I1_1423080161977"
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/payload?c=03AHJ_Vuu6vQefEcoVJVhsXZMpzEOGjONceHlLrKcofzhGVBUrTpA8ZPVEg_mptugxljlFIt-SoWOq8hmct9KaweK2NBXlS8oGNy6tZhsk4StFQijv51jQSGa3PcbL08KtttF3MoAgecD8VXFzQDXPb3iEyxLa5uE2wDbviNaEj7UsgH8C5dYtRSpRZ8s0iq50QywV-vAcSBsywYQOtO3Xi10lKlb4F8cHY0xvkse8zr3RqMMYWrqDzm5InTVNb-JJNtSvKPE6DJvzAFQw8ijaSorg3lwfL0VBSA&k=6LcIE_8SAAAAANQbcN_lbzBltZz-v4rrmivih_35
```

so please need your help

Answer (score 1):

Full example with imacros for recaptcha v2 as two files (add paidverts and you have the full solution):

1. recaptcha_v2.iim

   ```html
   VERSION BUILD=8920312 RECORDER=FX
   SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
   SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
   SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 999
   SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 999
   TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
   '
   ' The script fill the captcha of recaptcha v2 demo.
   '
   ' Note for users with firefox with the message "Firefox prevented this page from automatically reloading.":
   ' UNCHECK the option "warn me when pages try to redirect" in your browser
   ' You find the checkbox under Options > Advanced > General > Accessibility

   ' Path to the captcha image with timestamp
   ' Tempfolder like C:\ or C:\TEMP under windows or like /tmp under linux
   SET tempfolder C:\

   ' Tempslash (Path with slashs as tempfolder) and with the htmlfile recaptcha_v2.html
   SET tempslash C:/

   ' Tempfile
   SET tempfile captcha_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd_hhnnss}}.jpg

   ' Step 1: Config for 9kw.eu for your apikey
   SET apikey your_api_key
   'And priority (prio 1-20)
   SET prio 0

   ' Step 2: Save the captcha picture to local disk
   TAB T=1
   URL GOTO=https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo
   FRAME NAME=I0_*
   EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#recaptcha-anchor>DIV:nth-of-type(5)" BUTTON=0
   WAIT SECONDS=3
   ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER={{tempfolder}} FILE={{tempfile}} WAIT=YES
   FRAME NAME=I1_*
   TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:rc-imageselect CONTENT=EVENT:SAVE_ELEMENT_SCREENSHOT
   WAIT SECONDS=5

   TAB OPEN
   TAB T=2
   URL GOTO=file:///{{tempslash}}recaptcha_v2.html?file:///{{tempslash}}{{tempfile}}
   WAIT SECONDS=5
   FILEDELETE NAME={{tempfolder}}{{tempfile}}
   TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=* CONTENT=EVENT:SAVE_ELEMENT_SCREENSHOT
   TAB CLOSE

   'Wait a random number (1 to 5) of seconds
   SET randomnumber EVAL("Math.floor(Math.random()*5 + 1);")
   WAIT SECONDS={{randomnumber}}

   'Syntaxcheck: API Key, prio
   SET apikey EVAL("var s=\"{{apikey}}\"; if(s.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/) && s.length <= 50 && s.length >= 5) s; else MacroError(\"API Key is wrong.\")")
   SET prio EVAL("var s=\"{{prio}}\", d = parseFloat(s); if(d >= 0 && d <= 20) d; else MacroError(\"Value(Prio) is not in the set range.\")")

   'Step 3: Open the a new tab, and go to 9kw.eu, and submit the captcha picture
   TAB OPEN
   TAB T=2
   URL GOTO=http://www.9kw.eu/grafik/form.html
   'The apikey is used to identify each of our customers, which you can get from the our page. It is assigned to the CONTENT.
   TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:apikey CONTENT={{apikey}}
   'Priority in our system like min. 0 to max. 20 (cost +0-20)
   TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:prio CONTENT={{prio}}
   'Options for the form. See more under http://www.9kw.eu/grafik/form.html and http://www.9kw.eu/api.html
   TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ACTION:/index.cgi ATTR=NAME:selfsolve CONTENT=NO
   TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ACTION:/index.cgi ATTR=NAME:confirm CONTENT=NO
   TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ACTION:/index.cgi ATTR=NAME:case-sensitive CONTENT=NO
   TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ACTION:/index.cgi ATTR=NAME:nomd5 CONTENT=YES
   'We need only numbers for this captcha
   TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ACTION:/index.cgi ATTR=NAME:numeric CONTENT=YES
   TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:source CONTENT=imacros
   'The path of the captcha picture saved is assigned to the CONTENT
   TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:file-upload-01 CONTENT={{tempfolder}}{{tempfile}}
   'Submit the formdata to 9kw.eu
   TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=TYPE:submit
   'Extract the captchaid from your captcha submit
   TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:captchaid EXTRACT=TXT
   SET captchaid {{!EXTRACT}}
   'Clean the !EXTRACT variable for the next task
   SET !EXTRACT NULL
   'Extract the characters that are recoginzed from the picture of captcha.
   TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:result EXTRACT=TXT
   'Step 4: Check the captcha answer (text or nothing like #EANF#)
   SET answer EVAL("if (\"{{!EXTRACT}}\" == \"#EANF#\") {var x = \"\";} else {var x = \"{{!EXTRACT}}\";} x;")
   'Clean the !EXTRACT variable for the next task
   SET !EXTRACT NULL
   TAB CLOSE

   'Display extracted data (only for debug)
   'PROMPT {{captchaid}}

   'Step 5: Fill the recognized characters to the verification box (Click the pictures 1..9)
   TAB T=1
   FRAME NAME="I1_*"
   SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
   SET n1 EVAL("var s=\"{{answer}}\"; if(s.match(/^[0-9]+$/) && s.length <= 9 && s.length >= 2) s.substr(0,1); else MacroError(\"Captcha answer is wrong.\")")
   TAG POS={{n1}} TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/payload?c=*
   SET n2 EVAL("var s=\"{{answer}}\"; if(s.match(/^[0-9]+$/) && s.length <= 9 && s.length >= 2) s.substr(1,1); else MacroError(\"Captcha answer is wrong.\")")
   TAG POS={{n2}} TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/payload?c=*
   SET n3 EVAL("var s=\"{{answer}}\"; if(s.match(/^[0-9]+$/) && s.length <= 9 && s.length >= 2) s.substr(2,1); else MacroError(\"Captcha answer is wrong.\")")
   TAG POS={{n3}} TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/payload?c=*
   SET n4 EVAL("var s=\"{{answer}}\"; if(s.match(/^[0-9]+$/) && s.length <= 9 && s.length >= 2) s.substr(3,1); else MacroError(\"Captcha answer is wrong.\")")
   TAG POS={{n4}} TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/payload?c=*
   SET n5 EVAL("var s=\"{{answer}}\"; if(s.match(/^[0-9]+$/) && s.length <= 9 && s.length >= 2) s.substr(4,1); else MacroError(\"Captcha answer is wrong.\")")
   TAG POS={{n5}} TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/payload?c=*
   SET n6 EVAL("var s=\"{{answer}}\"; if(s.match(/^[0-9]+$/) && s.length <= 9 && s.length >= 2) s.substr(5,1); else MacroError(\"Captcha answer is wrong.\")")
   TAG POS={{n6}} TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/payload?c=*
   SET n7 EVAL("var s=\"{{answer}}\"; if(s.match(/^[0-9]+$/) && s.length <= 9 && s.length >= 2) s.substr(6,1); else MacroError(\"Captcha answer is wrong.\")")
   TAG POS={{n7}} TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/payload?c=*
   SET n8 EVAL("var s=\"{{answer}}\"; if(s.match(/^[0-9]+$/) && s.length <= 9 && s.length >= 2) s.substr(7,1); else MacroError(\"Captcha answer is wrong.\")")
   TAG POS={{n8}} TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/payload?c=*
   SET n9 EVAL("var s=\"{{answer}}\"; if(s.match(/^[0-9]+$/) && s.length <= 9 && s.length >= 2) s.substr(8,1); else MacroError(\"Captcha answer is wrong.\")")
   TAG POS={{n9}} TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/payload?c=*
   SET !ERRORIGNORE NO

   'Click the Verify button
   EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV" BUTTON=0
   WAIT SECONDS=2
   FRAME F=0
   EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV>FORM>FIELDSET>UL>LI:nth-of-type(6)>INPUT" BUTTON=0
   WAIT SECONDS=3

   'Step 6: Check and send the captcha feedback back to the captcha service (OK:1, NotOK:2, EN: Right/False, DE: Richtig/Falsch)
   TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:recaptcha-success EXTRACT=TXT
   SET htmlcode {{!EXTRACT}}
   SET !EXTRACT NULL
   SET feedback EVAL("if (\"{{htmlcode}}\" == \"Juhu!\") {var x = \"1\";} else {var x = \"2\";} x;")
   TAB OPEN
   TAB T=2
   URL GOTO=http://www.9kw.eu/index.cgi?source=imacros&action=usercaptchacorrectback&apikey={{apikey}}&correct={{feedback}}&id={{captchaid}}
   WAIT SECONDS=2
   TAB CLOSE
   TAB T=1

   'Cleanup: Delete the old captcha picture
   FILEDELETE NAME={{tempfolder}}{{tempfile}}
   ```
2. recaptcha_v2.html

   ```html
   <html>
   <head>
   <style>
   .c{
    width:392;
    height:505px;
    margin: -15px 0 0px -15px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
   }
   .t{
    position: absolute;
    top: 65px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 62%;
    border: 1px red solid;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    font: bold 18px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;padding: 0px 0px 0px 8px;
   }
   .n{
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    border: 1px red black;
    color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    font: bold 18px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;padding: 0px 0px 0px 8px;
   }
   .n1{
    top: 120px;
    left: 7px;
   }
   .n2 {
    top:120px;
    left:137px;
   }
   .n3 {
    top:120px;
    left:267px;
   }
   .n4 {
    top:250px;
    left:7px;
   }
   .n5 {
    top:250px;
    left:137px;
   }
   .n6 {
    top:250px;
    left:267px;
   }
   .n7 {
    top:380px;
    left:7px;
   }
   .n8 {
    top:380px;
    left:137px;
   }
   .n9 {
    top:380px;
    left:267px;
   }
   </style>
   <body>

   <div class='c'>
    <script>
     var href = window.location.href;
     var queryString = href.substring( href.indexOf('?') + 1 );
     document.write("<img src='"+queryString+"' width='400' height='600'>");
    </script>
    <span class='t'>Type the image numbers<br />without spaces as &quot;268&quot;</span>
    <span class='n n1'>1</span>
    <span class='n n2'>2</span>
    <span class='n n3'>3</span>
    <span class='n n4'>4</span>
    <span class='n n5'>5</span>
    <span class='n n6'>6</span>
    <span class='n n7'>7</span>
    <span class='n n8'>8</span>
    <span class='n n9'>9</span>
   </div>

   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Or under https://www.9kw.eu/grafik/plugins/9kweu_recaptcha_v2.zip with a captcha service(you can use any) like 
[9kw.eu](http://www.9kw.eu), captcha overlay (as text captcha as result) and captcha feedback.

NOTE TO THE MOD: The question was not identical but my solution is for both(!) threads and very helpful. Good solution for the problem from the threadcreator. This posting is without ANY link and ONLY with the solution in imacros. Mods on stackoverflow are really crazy, the solution for free is not okay but advertising with domainname from other users without any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have examples on deathbycaptcha.com but to access the API you have to register and buy captchas.

Answer (score -1):

I've done captchas in imacros before, however, with a more complex robust architecture.

You'll need a captcha service to help. Here is a link to an imacros example in one captcha service. You can research and find one you link, the script should be simliar

http://karmaproject.co.uk/how-to-solve-captcha-with-deathbycaptcha-in-imacros/